# How to send different messages to users with different settings? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

First of all, I'm a beginner at discord.py. It's hard to explain my problem but I'll try my best:

I'm trying to make a single command which sends different messages to users with different settings.

For example:
Let's say my bot has 2 commands `!command` and `!settings`.
A user changes his/her setting with the setting command: **"!settings (setting1/setting2/setting3/setting4...)"**
If the user uses the `!command` with (setting1), it will send "response1". But if user has (setting2) it will send "response2", and if user has (setting3) it will send "response3" and so on...

I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

**I will try my best to explain to you!**
To make it happen, we need to store those data in the database!(*what is database? to store some data which we can update, delete, and use anytime.*) So, we are going to store it in the database. (*what we are going to store? we are going to store each user's settings*)
For Example! if a person used *!settings 1* then we are going to store it in database like this.
`{ "user_id": discord_user_id_here,"settings":1}`
the discord user id of each person is unique so we use that to store it in the database!.(*but where we are going to store it? there is a free best company called "MongoDB" is providing us free database! we will save our data there. and we can completely control it with python*)
Now we have saved that user in database and we can do anything in that! but now the important thing, after saved when he uses the first command "!command", we need to fetch the settings from the database! and we can run anything according to his settings!.
**LINKS:**
MongoDB - https://www.mongodb.com/ 
MongoDB python Docs - https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ 
Complete Best Tutorial For MongoDB python - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE_bJl2GAY8

Comment: Unrelated to the original question, but how much data can one store in MongoDB?

Comment: can you explain me, how it is unrelated ?

Comment: It was only unrelated because the original question asked by Ramza was, "How to send different messages to users with different settings? discord.py". My question, unrelated to his, was how much data can you store in MongoDB? I was just curious beacuse that's something I might need to use.

Sorry for the confusion.